# What does 頭をひねった mean?

Tags: meaning

An example is (Tanaka and the speaker are in a relationship.):

> どれだけあたしと田中さんが頭をひねったか
>   (I think it means something like) How long have Tanaka and I...

頭をひねった doesn't make much sense literally, so I'm not sure about it.

Comment: I read an example somewhere, could it mean "racking your brain" or "thinking hard"? Like in 頭をひねったが打開策が見付からなかった?

Comment: Have you tried a [dictionary](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E9%A0%AD%E3%82%92%E6%8D%BB%E3%82%8B)? I think you have found the answer, though.

Answer (score 2):

Consider "scratching your head".

I suspect the person who downvoted here may not realize that this expression has two (semi-related yet distinct) meanings:

1. An intensive mental process trying to find some answer or solution, with at least the potential that such answer or solution might actually be found. This is the case where one might use the "rack your brain" translation.
2. Wondering about or being confused or puzzled by something. One reference describes this as 「疑問に思う」, and gives as an example 「高すぎる見積もりの数字に頭をひねる」. There is no notion that your mental activity is going to resolve the confusion; you're just stating that your brain was spinning because you are (or were) confused or surprised or couldn't understand something. This is the case where one is better off with the "head scratching" translation. In the example above: "The high estimate left me scratching my head", or perhaps more colloquially, "The estimate was head-scratchingly high".

The English word "puzzle" actually works for both, with slight variations:

1. "how much Tanaka and I puzzled over this"
2. "how puzzled Tanaka and I were by this"

Answer (score 1):

"puzzle over" might be the one option. Ex. 昨日の変な天候にどれだけあたしと田中さんが頭をひねったか、言葉で表現するのは難しい (puzzle over the weird weather)

Another option is "devise" or "contrive".　Ex. この問題を解決するためにどれだけあたしと田中さんが頭をひねったか、あなたにはわからないだろう

Comment: Perhaps it's 首を傾げる?

Comment: 首をひねる,  頭をひねる and 首をかしげる all mean "puzzle over" cf. https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%A0%AD%E3%82%92%E6%8D%BB%E3%82%8B-425293  and   https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%A6%96%E3%82%92%E5%82%BE%E3%81%92%E3%82%8B-484719

Comment: 「頭をひねったが打開策が見つからなかった」はいいですが、「首を傾げたが打開策が見つからなかった」とはいいませんね？

Comment: そうですね。ただそれは頭をひねるに「いろいろと思いを巡らす、工夫する」という意味もあるからで、これは「首をかしげる」にはない意味のようです。そうすると、私の回答は質問者様の答えにはなっていませんでしたね。コメントありがとうございました。

Comment: Is the どれだけ in the question short for どれぐらいでしたっけ？

Comment: @ナウシカ どれだけ is a synonym of どれほど. It doesn't come from anything else (besides どれ and だけ).